# when using youtube_DL with discord.py it gives this error

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl

```
[tls @ 000001c8ffbfef00] Error in the pull function.
[https @ 000001c8ffb40cc0] Will reconnect at 180224 in 0 second(s), error=I/O error.
[tls @ 000001c88156c180] Error in the pull function.
[https @ 000001c8ffb40cc0] Will reconnect at 360448 in 0 second(s), error=I/O error.
[tls @ 000001c8ffbfef00] Error in the pull function.
[https @ 000001c8ffb40cc0] Will reconnect at 540672 in 0 second(s), error=I/O error.
[tls @ 000001c8ffbe5480] Error in the pull function.
[https @ 000001c8ffb40cc0] Will reconnect at 704512 in 0 second(s), error=I/O error.
```

and mostly on the account, I have never used youtubedl I don't understand the errors.
i have tried to look it up but I cant find any relevant material

```py
@client.command(brief="Plays a single video, from a youtube URL")
async def play(ctx, url):
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    

    if not voice.is_playing():
        with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
        await ctx.guild.change_voice_state(channel=channel, self_mute=False, self_deaf=True)
        voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
        await ctx.guild.change_voice_state(channel=channel, self_mute=True, self_deaf=True)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Already playing song")
        return
```